# Unable to find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingCache]. Make sure that the as

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, blob-cache

I am trying to flush cache here,

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell

$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "https://portal2.zchech.com/"
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingCache]::FlushBlobCache($webApp)
Write-Host "Flushed the BLOB cache for:" $webApp
```

Error

> Unable to find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingCache].
>   Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded. At
>   line:7 char:1
>   + [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingCache]::FlushBlobCache($webApp)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Share...PublishingCache:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Comment: did you try to open the SharePoint Powershell instead of windows powershell...Start> all program> Microsoft SharePoint 2013 Products> SharePoint Management shell....RIght click and run as administrator

Comment: makes no difference as he is adding the dll, its the first line in his code

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure the account that your using has the right privlages to clear the cache.

2) is your blob enabled for the given web application?

goto webapps web.config and look for:

```
<BlobCache
```

if `enabled=false` than set it to `true` and then performe your powershell code.

3) run powershell as admin, right click powershell rather than double or single click and select run as administrator. This will open it up as admin level. If you have your code within a .ps1 (powershell) file than drag and drop the file into powershell and hit enter, it should then work!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg277249(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thank You blob is not enabled in webcongidation and account has permissions rightly

Comment: does your code work now?

Comment: not working same error since now

Comment: goto C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL and make sure the dll exists?